# Laravel custom urls saved in database

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I want to give custom urls to members of my site to have their pages under my site url like www.mysite.com/{theirurls}.
In database in **user** table i have a field **userurl** that keeps the url i give them.
In **route** i have written the code

```
Route::get('/{fpage?}', 'AController@fofpage');
```

In controller in **fofpage** function i take the variable and look for the value in database. If it belongs to someone redirects to this. If it isnt goes back to / (root).
The problem is that all the other urls like **login** and others doesnt work.
How can i solve this problem? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this route at the end of the `web` routes file to make it work:

```
Route::get('/{fpage?}', 'AController@fofpage');
```

You'll also want to validate user URLs and not allow users to enter values like `login`, `register` etc.

Comment: Thanks man your answer solved my problem. I didnt remember that the position of the route sentences matters.